# Android peripheral BLE advertisement sometimes returns an undocumented error code

Tags: java, android, android-bluetooth

I'm using the Android `BluetoothManager` to open a `BluetoothGattServer` and advertise using a `BluetoothLeAdvertiser`. Example snippet:

```
...
AdvertiseData advertiseData = new AdvertiseData.Builder()
                .setIncludeTxPowerLevel(true)
                .addServiceUuid(new ParcelUuid(myServiceUUID))
                .build();
mBluetoothLeAdvertiser.startAdvertising(advertiseSettings, advertiseData, scanResponse, mAdvertiseCallback);
```

Sometimes, on a particular device running Android 9 (Droidlogic w400), I get an error from my `mAdvertiseCallback`:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/le/AdvertiseCallback#onStartFailure(int)

The docs claim the code is "int: Error code (see ADVERTISE_FAILED_* constants) for advertising start failures." so I should get some idea of the cause.

However the `ADVERTISE_FAILED_*` constants only include values 1-5, and the `int` I'm getting is 12.

Has anyone had experience getting undocumented error codes like this before? Unfortunately I cannot say what causes the error. It seems random. Most of the time my advertisement and the whole BLE GATT server works perfectly.

Update -
After some testing I figured out I can reproduce it by having my central device connected to the peripheral while I restart the android app from Android Studio. The connection callback confirms the same device is connected instantly after I initialize the GATT server. That's great because it revealed my central device was failing to respond to the android app closing, but the error code still remains a bit of a mystery.

Comment: In my case, it returns 9.  I also restart it via the android studio 'Play ' button

Comment: were you able to figure out the mysterious error code?

Comment: I was not, unfortunately. :/